# Nest INDIRECT function into IF statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an `IF` statement:

```
=IF( 'Spray Record 1'!$A$7=0,"",'Spray Record 1'!$A$7)
```

Where: `Spray Record` is the name of the sheet I want to reference,
`A7` is the cell I want to reference on each sheet. If the cell is empty, I want to return no value, if it is filled, I want the contents returned.

I want to be able to write a statement to drag and fill that keeps `A7` constant (thus `$$`) but changes reference from `Spray Record 1` to `Spray Record 2` and so on. I have tried nesting an `INDIRECT` function but it is befuddling me.

I have:

```
=IF(INDIRECT(A40&"!'Spray Record 1'!A7")="","",INDIRECT(A40&"!'Spray Record 1'!A7"))
```

Where `A40`, `A41`..... are helper cells that contain the name of each sheet.

In short, I want to have the referenced sheet change sequentially as the formula is dragged and filled but keep the cell referenced within each worksheet the same `A7`.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the answer:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("'"&A40&"'!"&$B$40)=0,"",INDIRECT("'"&A40&"'!"&$B$40))
```

Comment: Hello, would be nice if you provided some details about your answer.